# Problems booting into recovery magisk (Android 12)

Tags: samsung, root-access, magisk

I rooted my Samsung Note 10 running Android 12/One UI 4.1 using Magisk in recovery mode a few weeks ago, however since then I have only managed to successfully boot with Magisk once. I have tried many different timings of holding the power button and volume up button simultaneously to no avail.

What I've been told is that the timing is to wait for the last warning splash screen and then let go, so I tried that a few times and it didn't work.

The one time it did work I held the buttons until the SAMSUNG logo splash screen (after the warnings) when the phone vibrates, then it shows something along the lines of

```
[PDP] 
back-up: fail 
setup-wizard: success
```

but when I go to the Magisk app it shows N/A in the installed field and the su command in terminal doesn't work.

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to reliably boot into Magisk or if there's anything I'm doing wrong.
Thank you for your help <3

Comment: what happens when you type su in terminal

Comment: @alecxs nothing, said it's an unknown command. i managed to reliably boot to recovery using adb (`adb reboot recovery`) so i've been using that to get into root lately

Comment: I have the same issue, but I was never able to get the root to work. By any chance, were you able to solve it?